# Gif image for MBProgress HUD ios8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, mbprogresshud

i am using MBProgress hud to show progress with gif image in HUD. its working fine in ios7.
     Can any one knows how we can do it for ios8?

I am using Latest MBProgress Library

Comment: What error did you met ?

Comment: i did not got any error but its not showing gif image over loader in ios8

Comment: You can post more detail in your code.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you step through the code to see if the gif is present?

Comment: i got solutions thnks

Comment: Post link on solution

Comment: @subhasghai Could you post the link to your solution